# When we say a mathematical object has algebraic+geometric structure?

Tags: geometry

When we say a mathematical object has algebraic+geometric structure, what does it mean by geometric structure?

Does it mean a analytic structure or else?

Comment: Example 1.2.11 in Tom Leinster‘s book on category theory (free available online) makes a comment about this (a functor $\mathbf{Top} \to \mathbf{Ring}$).

Comment: @QiZhu, thank you a lot